# How could I use Rfc2898DeriveBytes in window mobile?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, encryption

I am carrying out a PDA version application from windows version.
But found out Rfc2898DeriveBytes isn't supported by WM.
So how could I do to replace this piece of code in WM and change nothing about the algorithm?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check out this on koders.com, it is part of the DotGNU Portable .NET source.

'[DeriveBytes.cs](http://www.koders.com/csharp/fidB59CD8FE2B795FC7B3FFCCD6AC95575EAA411467.aspx)'

'[Rfc2898DeriveBytes](http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid42100A04C86EF9C6821CE54D50589916EAD4DE40.aspx)' *(This is a inherited class from DeriveBytes...)*

On another note, you could check the OpenNETCF [Smart Device Framework Community Edition](http://www.opennetcf.com/Products/SmartDeviceFramework/tabid/65/Default.aspx), they have a `DeriveBytes` class, so you could extend it by inheriting from it to make the `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` implementation by copying/pasting the code from koders.com.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the first answer is that you could build your own. The RFC2898 spec is [here](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2898.txt).

That would be the only way I know of to get exactly the same features. The easiest way might be to combine some of the algorithms in the documentation.

Whilst I have not used them, I am told that [OpenNetCF](http://www.opennetcf.com/Products/SmartDeviceFramework/tabid/65/Default.aspx) community edition has passwordDeriveBytes. So you might be able to make use of that if the license is right.